# Why is the endomorphism ring of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ noncommutative?

Tags: ring-theory

So I hear that the endomorphism ring of an abelian group is not always commutative. In particular, I'm looking at the abelian group $A=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, and considering $\text{End } A$. I can't find a counterexample to show that $\text{End } A$ is not commutative. Does anyone know of two such endomorphisms that don't commute?

Comment: Can you find two matrices with integer entries for which $AB \neq BA$?

Comment: If you pick two endomorphisms of $\mathbb Z$ you will find they do commute (do do this). So let's do the “next” case: if you pick a pair of endomorphisms of $\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z$ more or less however you want, you will find that they don't commute. It is just a matter of trying until you find an example. You *should* try!

Answer (score 13):

Hint: try to show that the ring $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ of $2 \times 2$ matrices with $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients acts <s>effectively</s> faithfully on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ by endomorphisms.  This is a non-commutative ring, so this will answer your question.

More generally, if $A$ is an abelian group and $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, then one can show that $\operatorname{End}(A^n) = M_n(\operatorname{End}(A))$.  (It happens that the endomorphism ring of the group $\mathbb{Z}$ is canonically isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb{Z}$, so the previous paragraph is a special case of this.)  This gives many examples of non-commutative endomorphism rings.

Comment: Thanks Pete, what do you mean "acts effectively"? Following @Theo Buehler's comment, I found A=[0 1// 2 0] and B=[0 2 // 1 0] to be $2\times 2$ matrices which do not commute, but how does this help exactly?

Comment: I mean that there is an injective homomorphism $M_2(\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \operatorname{End}(\mathbb{Z}^2)$.  In other words, distinct matrices give rise to distinct endomorphisms.

Comment: @Dom: you may have seen this called acting "faithfully", rather than "effectively".

Comment: Thanks, @Chris.  Both terms are widely used but upon reflection I prefer *faithfully* for ring actions.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I'm actually trying to show that $M_{n}(\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to $End(\mathbb{Z}^{n})$ in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2153885/prove-that-the-rings-end-mathbbzn-and-m-n-mathbbz-are-isomorphi Would you be willing to take a look at it and help me out?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I will be grateful if you can give me a reference for the $\operatorname{End}(A^n) = M_n(\operatorname{End}(A))$ result, I need it!

Comment: @Santropedro: This result is basic enough that it is more likely to appear as an exercise in standard texts than as a result with a proof.  One way to prove it is to show that $\operatorname{Hom}(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n A_i, B) = \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Hom}(A_i,B)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(A,\bigoplus_{i=1}^n B_i) = \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Hom}(A,B_i)$.  Another way is to adapt the basic linear algebra result that endomorphisms of finite-dimensional vector spaces over a field correspond to matrices.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Thank you very much! I'm grateful, you are awesome!

Answer (score 11):

Every ring acts by left multiplication as endomorphisms of its underlying abelian group ("Cayley's theorem for rings"), so if you believe that there exist non-commutative rings, then you already believe that there exist non-commutative endomorphism rings.

Comment: I love the way you phrased that.

Answer (score 9):

I know other people have given good answers but here's an explicit example:
$\phi : (a,b) \mapsto (b,a)$ and $\theta: (a,b) \mapsto (a+a,b)$
both are homomorphisms from $A$ to $A$, but the order you apply them matters.

Answer (score 5):

An endomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ can be represented as a $2\times2$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{Z}$, and all such matrices give endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.  (The ones with determinant 1 give automorphisms.)

So any two $2\times 2$ matrices that don't commute will provide you with an example.

Comment: Thanks, I think this answered my question in Pete L. Clark's answer above.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** $\rm\ \ \ a\ x + y\:\ \ne\:\ a\ (x+y)\ \ $ if $\rm\ \ a\ne 1$

$\quad\ $ i.e. $\rm\ \ \ \ \ (x,\:y)\ \mapsto\ (a\:x,\:y) $

$\quad$ and $\rm\ \ \ \ \:(x,\:y)\ \mapsto\ (x+y,\:y)\ \ $ do not commute.